# I found a unknown script in blogger theme

Tags: javascript, google-api, blogger

Can someone familiar with blogger tell me what is this script doing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = '//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/google_top_exp.js';
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
if (head) {
head.appendChild(script);
}})();
</script>
```

I tried to see what in this file //pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/google_top_exp.js is, but the code is minified and hard to read.

Comment: change the title.......

Comment: it wont impress anyone.

Comment: I just want so see if someone knows what is this script doing, i didn't found anything on google, except one man saying it's for comments.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh do you know what is this script doing?

Comment: posted as an answer.

Comment: @Marian07 [jsBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) is your friend ; ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer.

The code is from blogger navigation bar.

Comment: yeah .. even if we delete that js code the script automatically added. any clues how to remove this from the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = '//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/google_top_exp.js';
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
if (head) {
head.appendChild(script);
}})();
```

1) This is an anonymous self invoked function.

2) in this function, You are creating a script element:

```
script = document.createElement('script');
```

3) giving an src for the js file:

```
script.src = '//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/google_top_exp.js';
```

4) getting element head:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
```

5) then if there is a head element contained in the document then append the script element to the head

```
if (head) {
head.appendChild(script);
}})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, probably I expressed wrong, i don't know what does the script file '//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/google_top_exp.js'

Answer (score 1):

I created a blogspot [educational blog](https://hindi.sarkariletter.com) a couple of days ago and also redirected it to a custom domain. I published two blog posts on it.

One day, I was visiting the blog and had the Ad-blocker ON on the site, I was that it was blocking 1 ad. When I whitelisted the website, it showed nothing.

Then, going to the "view source" option. I came across the same script you are talking about.

I was shocked because who wants any code to appear on site without any permission. Then, I researched it and came to know that it code automatically appears on every newly created blog (the blogspot blog). This is highly likely to appear when you create a blog and do nothing (i.e. when you do not post on the regular basis).

The code on my theme is located under:

```
<div id="navbar-iframe-container">
```

So, if you want it to go away, you should publish around 2-3 posts every day and it will be long gone. By the way, even if it is there, it is not going to do anything bad, nor will it show an ad on your blog.

Answer (score 0):

Its inserted by blogger. Try removing it from the theme using theme > 'edit html' and then save and refresh the script will appear again. I think its probably injected by blogger itself. And when you run the page, it usually shows as

```
window['google_empty_script_included'] = true;
```

So probably its used for adsense, and shouldn't be something to worry about.